# How to trigger a event immediately after show a jQuery dialog?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'm working on a script that builds a schema using images inside a jQuery Ui Dialog. This dialog is opened by an anchor click. I need to place an image using as reference the position of another image. The problem is that it seems that while the dialog has not been shown, I can't retrieve the correct position of my reference image.

So, I need a way to trigger an event immediately after showing the dialog, so I can place the image correctly.

There's any way of doing it?

Kind Regards,

Answer (score 0):

**create**

*Type:* **dialogcreate**

This event is triggered when dialog is created.

Supply a callback function to handle the create event as an init option.

```
$( ".selector" ).dialog({
   create: function(event, ui) { ... }
});
```

Bind to the create event by type: dialogcreate.

```
$( ".selector" ).bind( "dialogcreate", function(event, ui) {
  ...
});
```

http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#event-create

Comment: that will be called on create, IE before the dialog is opened. its not what he wants i think.

Answer (score 0):

use [open event](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#event-open)

```
$( ".selector" ).dialog({
   open: function(event, ui) { ... }
});
```

that function gets called everytime the dialog is opened